# Angular ngClick not executing

Tags: angular, angular8

- I am beginner in **angular 8**. I am trying to develop admin panel. So here i am using **angular** as **client-side**. and **codeIgniter** as **server-side**.
- I am also using **dpGrid** for listing. Here, i am sending listing response from codeIgniter.
- Ex. Below is listing view Image.[image]

> - **dpGrid.js**

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      url: data.source, 
      async:false, 
      data: param, 
      success: function(responseData){ 
          tmpData=JSON.parse(responseData); 
      }
   });
```

- **Student.competent.ts**

  ```
  ngOnInit() {    
    this.studentGrid();    
  }

  studentGrid() {
    this.gridConfig = this.getGridConfig();
    $('#table-responsive').dpGrid(this.gridConfig);
  }

  testClick() {
    console.log('testClick');
  }
  ```

  - **Student.php** ---- Student Controller from CodeIgniter
    This controller is generate grid and below is operation tab code i want to use **ngClick** in edit icon.

  [image]

  - here, angular is first load view then after dpGrid called that's why ngClick is not working. **Give me the solution how to handle click event while html is comming from ajax.**

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged Angular8 as your version, I assume you are just using the wrong syntax. Use `(click)="testClick()"` instead.

Comment: Then please specify the version of Angular you are using. There is a big difference between AngularJS and Angular >2.

Comment: Application Version is **angular 8.1.3**

Comment: You are using AngularJS syntax in your code. Also, I do not understand how the php code (including Angular syntax) gets transpiled to Javascript.

Comment: I am calling **studentGrid()** on page load which is in angular. **studentGrid()** is calling **dpGrid**. dpGrid is in javascript. ajax is calling from dpGrid and student.php is in codeIgniter. Student.php is return listing html. These all process are done after page load so angular click event can't re render.

Comment: This does not work, you have to reconsider this structure/workflow. Angular has to be transpiled to Javascript, you can't just expect Angular syntax from external sources to work after transpilation has already happened.